# Shorten Link with php and API

Tags: php, function, curl

I already have a function on my page that produces url from curl. I need to use the following string to return short url in text format or "simple" using the shortswitch.com api.

Here Is my code:

```
<?php
$long_url = urlencode('curPageURL()');
$url = "http://api.shortswitch.com/shorten?apiKey=[apikey]&format=simple&longUrl={$long_url}";
$result = file_get_contents($url);
print_r($result);
?>
```

I'm attempting to use a function I found for bit.ly to use with shortswitch.com api as  shortswitch.com/admin/api.

My problem is that I'm not getting any type of output from the function, no shortened url is being generated.

best regards,

Comment: You can edit your question instead of adding a comment.

Comment: so what dont work, have you read the [docs?](http://shortswitch.com/admin/api)

Comment: I'm not getting any type of output from the function, no shortened url is being generated. Yes, I have read the api documentation.

Comment: The string "curPageURL()" is not any sort of valid URL that could be shortened, hence the service is probably not producing any result. Why would you expect that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just guess that you're actually trying to *call* the function `curPageURL()` and url encode *its result* instead of url encoding the string "curPageURL()":

```
$long_url = urlencode(curPageURL());
```

Comment: I figured it was something simple! Thanks @deceze